# How to correctly size separate index and data disks in Couchbase?

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase

According to this link: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/data-vs-index-paths/3564
And others I've read, it is beneficial to separate the data and index paths.

I'm going to be spinning up some new servers on EC2 and I am thinking of creating a separate path for the index and data by attaching an EBS volume for each.

However, while I would previously have lumped everything together on say a single 256MB EBS volume, I'm now unsure what size to make them.  Should I make them the same size or different?  Should the index be a proportion of the other (e.g. 10% of the data size).  Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: It more depends on what your View Indexes will look like, i.e. how much data will be emitted into the index, what percentage of the entire data set is looked at, how many data mutations per second and how much head room to leave for compaction. Since I know nothing about your data or the views, it is difficult to tell you exactly. Can you tell me such things as: 1) What is the data set size? 2) How many view indexes will there be? 3) How much of the overall data set size will be captured in each view index? 4) How many write and updates per second will you have?